# What is better in IN()? Sub-query or list of values

Tags: mysql

If search or update rows and use where statement IN() - is better to select values with sub-query or define values or there is no efficiency difference between this? For example:

```
SELECT a FROM b WHERE c IN( SELECT c FROM x )
```

OR

```
SELECT a FROM b WHERE c IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,...hundreds values...)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the values in a table and **the column is indexed**, I would expect it to be more efficient than using a list of values. Note that there are several ways to so this - especially because this type of queries (`WHERE c IN (SELECT c FROM x)`) is not fully optimized in some, not so old, MySQL versions:

```
SELECT a FROM b WHERE c IN ( SELECT c FROM x ) ;
```

You could rewrite (if `x (c)` has no `NULL` values) as:

```
SELECT a FROM b WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE x.c = b.c ) ;
```

or (if `x (c)` has unique values) as:

```
SELECT b.a FROM b JOIN x ON x.c = b.c ;
```

So, now you have 4 versions to test. Actual behaviour of course ***depends*** on several more factors (besides query, indexing, versions) like table sizes, values distributions, mysql settings, memory available, other queries running, moon phase, disk efficiency, etc.

In all, the best thing to do is test in your environment, all the available options and choose what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for idea with EXISTS, in my environment it's 5x faster :)

Comment: @stix As you gain experience, you will likely found the EXISTS option works well for certain queries.  I find it works best when the result set without the extra table is smaller then the number of entries matching in the extra table.  In other cases, you may find it slower than one of the options provided.

Comment: @BillThor good point, thanks for the information